# Working examples of :after css selector w/ multiple background images?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I swear I've seen people add multiple background images to an element using the :after selector.  For whatever reason, I can't get it to work.  What am I doing wrong?  Can anyone point me to a working example?

```
#el li { background:url(image1.jpg) top center;}
#el li:after { background:url(image2.jpg) bottom center;}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "The ':before' and ':after' pseudo-elements can be used to insert generated content before or after an element's content." http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Blender notes, there is some type of dom node added as content to the end of the element's content. However, you also need to provide some kind of content AFAICT to make it work.

```
<ul id="el">
    <li>Hello world</li>
</ul>

#el li {
    background:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) top center no-repeat;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#el li:after {
    background:url(http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/05a3a91994b86e4e45246b57b0ec3c7d?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG) bottom center;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: -100;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QhUsS/

Comment: Thanks, Jared.  I didn't think of leaving content: "" blank.  Thanks = )

Answer (score 2):

`:before` and `:after` always need the following:

```
{
    content: '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With CSS3 it could be done by

```
#el li {
   background: url(image1.jpg), url(image2.jpg);
   background-position: top center, bottom center;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: He's asking how to do it with the pseudo-element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but I've never tried. `:after` seems to create an inline-like element after your element. You can try adding this CSS (no idea if it works):

```
display: block;

position: relative;
top: -200px;

height: 200px;
width: 200px;
```